Problem deriving the PDF of Y given Y = aX + b and the PDF of X
I was learning about the following property:
Let X be a continuous random variable with PDF $f_{X}$, and let
$$Y=aX+b$$
then for some scalar $a\neq$0 and $b$:
$$f_{Y} = \dfrac{1}{|a|}f_{X}\left(\dfrac{y-b}{a}\right)$$

The book I was learning from provided a proof of the property above in which  we find the CDF (cumulative distribution function) $F_{X}\left(\dfrac{y-b}{a}\right)$ and then take the derivative of it with respect to x to get the corresponding PDF(probability distribution function) of Y (i.e. $f_{Y}$).
I understood this proof but I wanted to test my understanding by proving the given property by directly trying to find its PDF ($f_{Y}$) without taking the CDF->PDF approach. To this end I did the following:
$f_Y(y) = P(Y=y) = P(aX+b=y) = P\left(X = \dfrac{y-b}{a}\right) = f_X\left(\dfrac{y-b}{a}\right) = 0,$
where the final 0 follows from the fact that for any specific value the PDF yields 0.
Obviously my answer is wrong and it fails to prove. I would appreciate if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong, and what would be the correct steps to take.
Thank you.

With respect to @lone_wolf's comment I modified my proof as follows.

Is it correct and if it is, is there a way to not use $\approx$ in the proof?

$f_{Y}(y)\delta y \approx P( y-\delta y < Y < y+\delta y)$, so when you write $f_{Y}(y)=P(Y=y)$ for a continuous random variable, It is incorrect.

Looked at another way, $P(Y=y)=0$ as a probability since $Y$ is a continuous random variable.  Meanwhile $f_Y(y)$ is a density rather than a probability (and can be positive) so not equal to $P(Y=y)$.

You got $\Pr(Y=y)=0$, which is correct but it does not give you any information about $f_Y$. The only way to find $f_Y$ directly without finding $F_Y$ is to what you have done, since a PDF is literally defined as a function $f_Y$ such that
$$\int_u^vf_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy=\Pr(u<Y<v)$$
for all $u$ and $v$. Now, assuming $a>0$,
$$\Pr(u<Y<v)=\Pr(u<aX+b<v)=\Pr\left(\frac{u-b}{a}<X<\frac{v-b}{a}\right)$$
So,
$$\int_u^vf_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy=\int_{(u-b)/a}^{(v-b)/a}f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
Substitute $z=ax+b$, then
$$\int_u^vf_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy=\int_u^v\frac{1}{a}f_X\left(\frac{z-b}{a}\right)\,\mathrm dz$$
Might as well write $z$ as $y$:
$$\int_u^vf_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy=\int_u^v\frac{1}{a}f_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)\,\mathrm dy$$
Since this is true for all $u$ and $v$, you can say that one choice of $f_Y$ that works is
$$f_Y(y)=\frac1af_X\left(\frac{y-b}{a}\right)$$
Hope this helps. :)
